# Reshaping CSV data by stacking columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, reshape

My dataset looks like this - from a csv file

```
0   100   1   100   2   100  3   100  4   100  5   100     
6   200   7   200   8   200  9   200  0   200  1   200  
.....
```

I want to reshape my dataset in the following format using python -

```
0 100
1 100
2 100
3 100
4 100
5 100
..
6 200
7 200
8 200
9 200
0 200
1 200
...
```

Comment: what is the data structure of your input and output? is it list or numpy array ?

Comment: Could you maybe give the structure of both datasets (so, where are all the dimensions)?

Comment: i am using the data from a csv file and it has 10 columns and atleast 50,000 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your data using `pd.read_csv` -

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\s+', header=None)
arr = df.values
```

Or, using `np.loadtxt` -

```
arr = np.loadtxt('file.csv')
```

Now, reshape and save -

```
np.savetxt('file.csv', arr.reshape(-1, 2), delimiter=',')
```

Or, if you want the result as a dataframe -

```
pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape(-1, 2)).set_index(0)

     1
0     
0  100
1  100
2  100
3  100
4  100
5  100
6  200
7  200
8  200
9  200
0  200
1  200
```

Comment: Thanks Coldspeed. Worked perfectly

Comment: @SafatMahmood As for your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179906/reshaping-data-in-csv-to-multiple-columns/48180019#48180019), you should reconsider which method you use (the current accepted answer is slower).

Comment: I needed to modify the dataset slightly so that I can use it to do the required task. By the way is there anyway you can tell me what if i want to add an empty line to separate my data from each row. (for example, and empty line betwwen all the 100 and 200 data)

Comment: @SafatMahmood I don't recommend doing that.